# Provide single config to Multiple AWS APIs with Lambda integrations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to write a simple API's using Amazon AWS API gateway with Lambda integration.

Lambda function to some computation by reading user input and some configuration.

How can I make both API's or lambda functions to use the same configuration without duplicating?

Correct me if i am using API gateway in wrong way.

Comment: Would you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am writing some analytics api where it extracts information from different machines. machine ip address mapping is given as config. two lambda functions should able to read the config.

Comment: Can you provide the code you that should be shared?

Comment: pseudocode : https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/33425fe457a6d346e6a2c622863c2aaa

Comment: You can store the config in s3 and read it in each Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways I can think of:

1. Create another lambda function which executes the common logic and invokes the corresponding lambda function with the data it processed.
   In your case:

   ```
   def lambda_handler(event, context):    
       config = load config from env variable.
       take service names from user input(event)
       extract corresponding micro services names mapped to feature name.
       check event.methodName to see which function to call next
       invoke {event.methodName}Lambda with the data
   ```
2. (Recommended) Consider using [Serverless](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/) where you define env variables only once and you can extract common logic into separate **(non-lambda) functions** which you can reuse in multiple **lambda functions**